# Что означает for

Tags: javascript, for

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что означает for в такой конструкции:

```
 <label for="sum">Сумма</label>
```

Как определить этот элемент по метке sum через querySelector() ?

```
 let sum = document.querySelector('#sum');
```

Правильно?

Я понял. Спасибо!

Вы не могли бы объяснить, чем отличаются ответы сразу после моего вопроса от ответов в поле "Ответы" ниже?

Как я понимаю, сначала идут комментарии а потом ответы?

Comment: `for` является аттрибутом который указывает на какой элемент формы (id) сфокусироваться если нажать на `label`. То есть нажав на поле `Сумма` то он сфокусируется на элементе у которого `id='sum'`

Comment: @E1mir Оформите свой комментарий как ответ

Comment: @Jaguar укажите в метках вопроса язык (языки) - например javascript, xml или что там вы используете.

Comment: @Jaguar Вот это поле вот, это комментарий к вашему вопросу, комментарий к вопросам иногда может содержать ответ на вопрос (если ответ бывает очень простым, например ссылка на какую-то статью или ресурс который поможет) а для ответов существует поле ответ, где можно развернуто написать ответ, описать проблему и показать как ее решить

Comment: Спасибо, я понял!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for` в теге `label` является аттрибутом который указывает на какой элемент формы (id) сфокусироваться если нажать на label. То есть в вашем случае, нажав на поле Сумма то он сфокусируется на элементе у которого `id='sum'`.

Внизу наглядный пример:

```css
input {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<label for="sum">Сумма</label><br>
<input id="sum" placeholder="Общая сумма" />
```

А вот чтобы достучаться до элемента элемента то можно сделать следующим способом.

```js
let sumLabel = document.querySelector('label[for="sum"]');
console.log(sumLabel)
```

```css
input {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<label for="sum">Сумма</label><br>
<input id="sum" placeholder="Общая сумма" />
```

Или же можно просто задать класс или id данному элементу и обратиться к нему

```html
<label class="label-sum" for="sum">Сумма<label>
<!-- Или же указать id -->
<label id="label-sum" for="sum">Сумма<label>
```

```js
let labelSum = document.querySelector('.label-sum')
// Если у элемента есть id
let labelSum = document.querySelector('#label-sum')
```

Comment: Я понял. Спасибо!

Comment: @Jaguar Я обновил ответ